# div with shape on both sides at middle

Tags: html, css

I have a div using radial gradient. How can I put a semicircle on the left and right side and keep the background color as red itself?

```css
.container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 58px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  background: radial-gradient(semi-circle at left, semi-circle at right)
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69353608/8620333 ?

Comment: yes similar but just want the left and right just like a semi curv

Comment: define "semi curv" .. you said in your question "semi circle", if they are not the same you have to give more detail

Comment: sorry i meant same

Comment: so like the link I sent?

Comment: let me check if i can share you the exact shape what i am looking out

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xxboAxY

Comment: @TemaniAfif i was able to achieve it but the border is not working its not working for the gradient. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74105686/making-the-border-for-the-radial-gradient-also can you help

Comment: Sorry to ask again @TemaniAfif since was closed to 99% of the solution but not able to get the border for curve, any way or any help